# In IIS, I need a temporary redirect to a page, and then continue to originally requested destination. Is this possible?

Tags: iis, redirect

We have some IIS web servers running many applications.  There may come a day where we want to display a message to the users of all applications on our servers.  Then we want them to be able to continue to their originally intended destination.

So, someone goes to https://www.example.com/AppName - I want them to be directed to something like https://www.example.com/LookHereFor10Seconds.html FIRST, and then after 10 seconds, they would continue on to https://www.example.com/appname (which is what they originally requested).

I'm thinking we'd want this to load one time per visitor per application.

Any ideas how I can implement this entirely within IIS without touching any of the application code?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!